# Semi-colon or colon?

Tags: word-usage, clauses, semicolons, colons, rules

I'm writing a descriptive piece, and can't figure out whether this is grammatically correct, or whether I ought to place a semi-colon between "entry" and "crooked":

"As I walked in using the cobbled path, a squadron of pigeons nestled upon the roof observed my entry, their heads crooked towards me like a sniper’s gun is crooked on an enemy fighter."

My only line of thought was that, perhaps, in the last clause, rephrasing it to "their heads *were* crooked" would make the clause independent whereas without "were", as it is presented above, the clause is dependent?

Kind regards,

JP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would definitely use a comma. A semi-colon joins two related sentences and you have only one, albeit long, sentence.

If you do do "their heads were crooked" then you do have two sentences, but I would use a period, not a semi-colon.

I don't know your experience with English, but rarely do you need a semi-colon.  If you have 2 sentences, a period works.